# function and its second derivative in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ implies $f^\prime$ in $L^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Suppose $f$ is smooth and both $f$ and $f^{\prime\prime}$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Prove $f^{\prime}$ is again in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
Someone said I can use the method of Fourier transform. Because since $f$ and $f^{\prime\prime}$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then we must have
$$
\int |\hat f(\xi)|^2 <\infty \quad \text{and} \int  |\xi|^4 |\hat f(\xi)|^2 <\infty,
$$
and hence, by Holder's inequality,
$$
\int |\xi|^2 |\hat f(\xi)|^2 <\infty-(*).
$$
It says in a text book that only if $f^{(k)}$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $\widehat{(f^{(k)})}=(i\xi)^k \hat f$. But in my problem, we do not know $f^\prime$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. So, my first question is, can we deduce the result by $(*)$?

My second question: I tried to use approximation theorem to figure this out. I hope to find a sequence of functions in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to approximate $f$. I know $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. But can we guarantee that the sequence also converges to the derivatives of $f$ at the same time? I know I can use mollifier to achieve this, but the approximation functions would not have compact support then.

Can someone give me an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Multiply by a smooth compactly supported function and then do the convolution by a mollifier to get sn approximation by a $C^\infty_c$ function, this is the way compactness of this space in Sobolev spaces is proved usually.

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

For any $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ open and bounded, choose $\psi$ s.t. $\psi \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ and $\psi \vert_{U^\prime} =1$, where $U^\prime$ satisfying $U \subset\subset U^\prime$. Consider $g=f\psi$.
Let $\{\eta^\epsilon\}$ be a family of mollifiers. Then,
$$
g^\epsilon\to f  \text{ in } L^2(U) \text{$\quad and \quad $} (g^\epsilon)^{\prime\prime} \to f^{\prime\prime}  \text{ in } L^2(U)
$$
Since we know $f$, $f^{\prime\prime}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\vert_U=f$.

Therefore,
$$
||\widehat{g^\epsilon}||_{L^2(U)}=||g^\epsilon||_{L^2(U)}\to ||f||_{L^2(U)}\leq ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})},
$$
and
$$
||\widehat{(g^\epsilon)^{\prime\prime}}||_{L^2(U)}=||(g^\epsilon)^{\prime\prime}||_{L^2(U)}\to ||f^{\prime\prime}||_{L^2(U)}\leq ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}.
$$
Now, since $g^{\epsilon}$ has compact support, then $\widehat{(g^\epsilon)^\prime}=i\xi \hat {g^\epsilon}$. It then follows from H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder's inequality and the above two that,
$$
||(g^\epsilon)^\prime||_{L^2(U)}=||\widehat{(g^\epsilon)^\prime}||_{L^2(U)}=||\xi \hat {g^\epsilon}||_{L^2(U)} \leq C (||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})},||f^{\prime\prime}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})})=:M.
$$
Notice that $M$ does not depend on $U$. Hence, there exists $h\in L^2(U)$ s.t.
$$
(g^\epsilon)^\prime \to h \text{ in } L^2(U) \text{ weakly up to a subsequence.}
$$
So, for any $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$,
$$
-\int g^\epsilon \phi^\prime=\int(g^\epsilon)^\prime \phi \to \int h\phi.
$$
But $\int g^\epsilon \phi \to \int f\phi$. So,
$$
\int f\phi^\prime=-\int h \phi,
$$
which implies that $h=f^\prime$ on $U$. Now, since $
(g^\epsilon)^\prime \to f^\prime \text{ in } L^2(U) \text{ weakly up to a subsequence,}
$ then we have
$$
||f^\prime||_{L^2(U)} \leq \liminf ||(g^\epsilon)^\prime||_{L^2(U)} \leq M.
$$
Since $U$ can be arbitratry, then $f^\prime \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.